# How to start the twm manager on a system which already has a window manager ?

Tags: command-line, window-manager, twm, xinit

I am using linux mint codename rebecca with xface. 
I tried to follow a description how to start a window manager of once choice:

1. created an empty .xinitrc file in my homefolder
2. filled the file with "exec twm"
3. ran command "xinit"

but all I got was a fatal error message and a message I did not understand:

> (EE)  Fatal server error: (EE) Server is already active for display 0
>     If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock   and start
>   again. (EE)  (EE)  Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
>   at http://wiki.x.org  for help.  (EE)

Could you tell me what I did wrong or what I missed to do.

Comment: twm does not support the protocol to replace window manager. Therefore you will have to kill the old one, and start twm. Also you should not start an X11 server, it is already running. So just kill existing wm, and run `twm`.